Boost graph library: subgraph edges referencing original graph edges
I want to have two types of graph (with different bundled properties, simplified below). One of the types is used to represent subgraphs of the other type, so i want to be able to map the vertices and edges of the subgraphs to their corresponding vertices and edges in the original graph.
`// main graph structure
struct VertexProperties
{
    ...
};
struct EdgeProperties{
    double cost;
    ...
};
using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::bidirectionalS, VertexProperties, EdgeProperties>;
using Vertex = boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor;
using Edge = boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor;

// subgraph structure
struct SubVertexProperties
{
    Vertex original_vertex;
};
struct SubEdgeProperties{
    Edge original_edge;
    ...
};

using SubGraph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::bidirectionalS, SubVertexProperties, SubEdgeProperties>;
using SubVertex = boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor;
using SubEdge = boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor;

I create one "original" graph of type Graph and many subgraphs of type SubGraph and at that point i can access edges of the original graph as i expect:
Graph g = ...;
SubGraph sg = ...; 
vector<int> sg_to_g_vertex; // maps each vertex in the subgraph to the corresponding vertex in original graph

for (auto e : make_iterator_range(edges(g))) {
     Vertex u = source(e, g);
     Vertex v = target(e, g);

    if (someCondition(u,v)) {
        boost::add_edge(vertex_map[u], vertex_map[v], {e, ...}, com_graph);
    }
}


for (auto e : make_iterator_range(edges(sg))
{
    std::cout << g[sg[e].original_edge].cost << std::endl;
}

This will print out the cost of the edge in the original graph that corresponds to each edge in the subgraph. Next i store both the original graph and the subgraphs in a struct which is passed around in my code. Once i pass this struct to another function, executing a loop like the last one above results in gibberish values. But if i print out the edges of my original and subgraphs and the associated bundled properties, they look just fine. So i assume the Edge identifiers original_edgeare not valid anymore. Is there a way to store such identifiers that they remain useable?
If it helps, after initial construction i do not add or delete vertices from either of these graphs.
I tried reading the boost documentation and all stackoverflow posts that sounded related, but i do not really understand what type these edge identifiers have and how i could obtain more stable ones.

What (and why) is vertex_map?

i see from your answer that you figured it out from my admittedly limited description :) for those reading later, it maps the vertex descriptors from the subgraph to the corresponding vertex descriptors in the main graph. It is abusing the fact that the vertex descriptors are integers and so the vector can be used to map them.

I didn't figure anything out ¯\(ツ)/¯ I merely conjectured two possible reasons, which perhaps helped you figure something out? The rest of my answer is basically my party trick where I show off my experience using Boost Graph Library. I do that because good examples help a lot more people than just straight "You have UB" answering.

Its a good party trick and i appreciate the effort :)

Simply put, something causes your data to get reallocated e.g.

due to passing by value instead of moving/passing by reference.
mutating the main Graph. The descriptor invalidation rules are documented here: Table: Summary of Descriptor and Iterator Invalidation

You need to include more code for us to point out the error.
Here's my imagined code that unsurprisingly doesn't have the issue. Note how it exemplifies both pass-by-reference and move-semantics:
Coliru
#include <boost/graph/random.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

// main graph structure
struct VertexProperties {
    //...
};
struct EdgeProperties {
    double cost;
    //...
};

using boost::adjacency_list;
using boost::bidirectionalS;
using boost::vecS;
using Graph  = adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, bidirectionalS, VertexProperties, EdgeProperties>;
using Vertex = Graph::vertex_descriptor;
using Edge   = Graph::edge_descriptor;

// subgraph structure
struct SubVertexProperties {
    Vertex original_vertex;
};
struct SubEdgeProperties {
    Edge original_edge;
    //...
};

using SubGraph  = adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, bidirectionalS, SubVertexProperties, SubEdgeProperties>;
using SubVertex = Graph::vertex_descriptor;
using SubEdge   = Graph::edge_descriptor;
using boost::make_iterator_range;

struct LinkedSubgraph {
    Graph const& g;
    SubGraph     sg;

    std::map<Vertex, SubVertex> vertex_map;
    std::vector<int> sg_to_g_vertex;

    LinkedSubgraph(Graph const& g, auto condition) : g(g) {
        for (auto e : make_iterator_range(edges(g))) {
            Vertex u = source(e, g), v = target(e, g);

            if (condition(u, v)) {
                sg_to_g_vertex.push_back(v);
                add_edge(sub_vertex_for(u), sub_vertex_for(v), SubEdgeProperties{e}, sg);
            }
        }
    }

    SubVertex sub_vertex_for(Vertex v) {
        auto it = vertex_map.find(v);

        if (it == vertex_map.end())
            it = vertex_map.emplace(v, add_vertex(SubVertexProperties{v}, sg)).first;

        return it->second;
    };

    void report() const {
        for (auto se : make_iterator_range(edges(sg))) {
            auto e = sg[se].original_edge;
            std::cout << " (" << e << ":" << g[e].cost << ")";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
};

struct MyStruct {
    Graph g;
    std::list<LinkedSubgraph> subgraphs;

    MyStruct() {
        std::mt19937 prng{std::random_device{}()};
        generate_random_graph(g, 10, 20, prng);
        for (auto e : make_iterator_range(edges(g)))
            g[e].cost = std::uniform_real_distribution<double>(1, 10)(prng);
    }

    void addSubgraph(auto condition) {
        subgraphs.emplace_back(g, condition);
    }

    void report() const {
        for (auto& sg : subgraphs)
            sg.report();
    }
};

static auto trisection(unsigned n) {
    return [n](Vertex u, Vertex v) { return (u % 3u) == n && (v % 3u) == n; };
}

void passByReference(MyStruct& data) {
    data.addSubgraph(trisection(0));
    data.report();
}

void passByValue(MyStruct data) {
    data.addSubgraph(trisection(1));
    data.addSubgraph(trisection(2));
    data.report();
}

int main() {
    MyStruct data;

    passByReference(data);
    std::cout << "----\n";
    passByValue(std::move(data)); // NOTE move!

    assert(data.subgraphs.empty()); // moved-from object is empty
}

Possible outputs like:

Simplify?
Note that given the question code, it could be vastly simplified using filtered_graph adaptors instead.
See it Live: 40% less code
That probably fits the actual problem less, because the subgraph adds properties to edges/vertices.
However, in that case I'd suggest adding external property maps instead, which is how BGL design shines best. Imagining some more:
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/filtered_graph.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/random.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map/transform_value_property_map.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
using boost::make_iterator_range;

// main graph structure
struct VertexProperties {};
struct EdgeProperties { double cost; };

using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::bidirectionalS, //
                                    VertexProperties, EdgeProperties>;
using Vertex = Graph::vertex_descriptor;
using Edge   = Graph::edge_descriptor;

using VertexFilter = std::function<bool(Vertex)>;
using EdgeFilter   = std::function<bool(Edge)>;
using SubGraph     = boost::filtered_graph<Graph, EdgeFilter, VertexFilter>;

struct MyStruct {
    Graph g;

    struct Entry : SubGraph {
        struct Extra { int a, b, c; };
        std::vector<Extra>                     vprop_storage{num_vertices(*this)};
        std::map<edge_descriptor, std::string> eprop_storage;

        using SubGraph::SubGraph;

        auto extra() {
            return make_safe_iterator_property_map(vprop_storage.data(), vprop_storage.size(),
                                                   get(boost::vertex_index, *this));
        }

        auto a_map() { return make_transform_value_property_map(std::mem_fn(&Extra::a), extra()); };
        auto b_map() { return make_transform_value_property_map(std::mem_fn(&Extra::b), extra()); };
        auto c_map() { return make_transform_value_property_map(std::mem_fn(&Extra::c), extra()); };

        auto edge_name() { return boost::make_assoc_property_map(eprop_storage); }
    };
    std::list<Entry> subgraphs;

    MyStruct(MyStruct&&)            = delete; // g needs to be stable
    MyStruct& operator=(MyStruct&&) = delete;

    MyStruct() {
        std::mt19937 prng{std::random_device{}()};
        generate_random_graph(g, 10, 20, prng);
        for (auto e : make_iterator_range(edges(g)))
            g[e].cost = std::uniform_real_distribution<double>(1, 10)(prng);
    }

    Entry& addSubgraph(auto condition) { //
        return subgraphs.emplace_back(g, boost::keep_all{}, condition);
    }

    void report() {
        for (auto& sg : subgraphs) {
            boost::dynamic_properties dp;
            dp.property("node_id", get(boost::vertex_index, sg));
            dp.property("label", sg.a_map());
            dp.property("color", sg.b_map());
            dp.property("shape", sg.c_map());
            dp.property("label", sg.edge_name());
            dp.property("cost", get(&EdgeProperties::cost, sg));
            write_graphviz_dp(std::cout, sg, dp);
        }
    }
};

void passByReference(MyStruct& data) {
    data.addSubgraph([](Vertex u) { return (u % 2u) == 0; });

    {
        auto& sg = data.addSubgraph([](Vertex u) { return (u % 2u) == 1; });
        for (auto name = sg.edge_name(); auto e : make_iterator_range(edges(sg)))
            name[e] = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(e);
    }

    data.report();
}

int main() {
    MyStruct data;
    passByReference(data);
}

With more live demos:


added some creative demos based on filtered_graph instead

Hi sehe, thank you so much for the insightful answer! I was not familiar with std::move at all.. I did suspect that passing by reference / value had something to do with it, but i couldnt work - i passed my object to one function by reference (everything was fine) then in that function i passed it by value to the constructor of a different object and after that both the object in the function and in the other object were broken, which i really did not understand.

As for the second suggestion with the filtered graph: i need to run algorithms on the subgraphs and i want them to be fast. For a previous project i used the filtered graph and the runtimes were significantly worse even though the filter was also just a vector of bool. in that project the main graph was huge and the subgraphs not much smaller, so in the end i decided to just run the algorithm on the full graph, since all subgraphs would not fit into memory. In this project the subgraphs are smaller so i can afford the extra memory they need.

For the record, check that the graphs are not mutating (because only precious few types of mutations do not invalidate references/descriptors/iterators to non-deleted elements). Const-correctness can be a real help, though sadly, some BGL features don't really assume const-correctness (looking at you, dynamic_properties).

Regarding performance, everything depends on the usage patterns. Your solution also incurs an indirection through original_vertex/original_edge. Depending on the relative volumes you might actually be faster with straight-up copies of the graph - since references thwart loads of optimizations. If anything, you can already simplify the lookup by storing a reference/pointer to the actual original property bundle instead of the descriptor. Of course, head the invalidation guarantees again when you do.

Also, look at CSR graphs since they have similar storage semantics for both vertices and edges (which might perhaps remove the problem that prompted the current question). I'd advocate for filtered_graph+copy_graph for achieving the copies as it is likely to optimize some of the copying (which can make a big difference). In the end: always try out different approaches and measure!

I am certain that the graphs are not changing after they have been initially constructed, i add additional property maps (for which i wrote my own, probably not great, class to allocate a vector for the memory and use the an ID i give each arc to access the values) to run my algorithms and these are the only graph-related things that change.

The point on indirection is valueable and i admit that i am not familiar really with what optimization i might prevent. In my case i mostly run algorithms on the subgraphs only and then need the main graph to coordinate and store results. I will keep it in mind if i need to squeeze more performance :)
